# Test class for the controller

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a controller and want to write the test class for this but dont know how to do it

```
public class EmployeeCtr {
     List<Employee__c> employee_list;
    public List<Employee__c> getEmployees()
    {
        employee_list = [SELECT ID, Name from Employee__c WHERE Reports_to__r.UserEmployee__c = :userinfo.getuserid()];
        return employee_list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To write unit tests, you basically create a new test class that:

- instantiates your class under test
- calls its public method(s)
- asserts that the return value(s) are what you expect

For instance, for testing your `EmployeeCtr` you can create 2 employees reporting to the current user, instantiate your `EmployeeCtr` and assert that you get 2 employees back. Could be something like this

```
@isTest
public class TestEmployeeCtr {

    @isTest
    public static void TestGetEmployeesReturnsEmployees ()
    {
        Employee__c employee1 = new Employee__c (Reports_to__c = userinfo.getuserid());
        Employee__c employee2 = new Employee__c (Reports_to__c = userinfo.getuserid());
        insert employee1;
        insert employee2;

        EmployeeCtr controller = new EmployeeCtr ();

        Test.startTest();
        List <Employee__c> employees = controller.getEmployees();
        Test.endTest();

        System.AssertEquals (2, employees.size());
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't run this code so it may have some compile errors.

Your test class should test many cases, perhaps like this:

- What happens when there are no employees in the system
- What happens when there are employees but they don't belong to the current user
- What happens when there are several employees belonging to different users (you can use the `System.runAs()` statement to help you test cases for different users).

Hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Look for the section 'Test Methods and Visualforce Controllers' on the following page:

[Writing test code for Visualforce controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)

Answer (score -1):

Rather then get a code and put it to your class you should better understand what the apex testing is and why an apex class should be tested.

I would recommend to read an [Understanding Testing in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_intro.htm). 
Another useful article is [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)